# Fixed position footer changing its position on opening new tab

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I am running into an issue with ios mobile safari.

Fixed position footer is not retaining its position on opening/closing a new tab on iphone safari browser.

Sometimes the footer moves up and sometimes it moves down - it depends on whether the address bar is visible or not.

I am not able to understand why safari mobile is behaving like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             height:100%
        }
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 48px;
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="footer">
          Bottom Fixed Footer.
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: try adding `html, body {height:100%}`

Comment: already tried this but no success, Updated question also